# Rails 3.1 + Heroku = Workers crashing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

So, I just stood up a brand new Rails 3.1.1 app (Ruby 1.8.7).

Put a few scaffolds in there, installed Authlogic, and created a new Heroku app.  Pushed it to Heroku and migrated the DB.

And all is well.  I can make new user accounts with Authlogic and make new records in my models on Heroku.

Funny thing, though.  If I increase my 'worker dynos' from zero to anything, the heroku logs show those workers trying to start and they crash.

**But, I don't have Delayed Job installed. And never introduced Delayed Job to this app**

I also haven't introduced any 'advanced' gems other than Twilio or any advanced code. It's just the new rails app with authlogic.  No new rake tasks either.

One other note:  On my local development machine, I tried to install Delayed Job on a different app a while back and failed.  Could the 'ghosts' of delayed job be haunting this new app?

Thanks!

code below.....

Heroku logs after I increase Web workers from 0 --> 2.

```
2012-04-01T11:44:04+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1, worker=2 by doug@goinfield.com
2012-04-01T11:44:07+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
2012-04-01T11:44:07+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec      rake jobs:work`
2012-04-01T11:44:08+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: State changed from starting to up
2012-04-01T11:44:08+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-04-01T11:44:11+00:00 app[worker.2]: rake aborted!
2012-04-01T11:44:11+00:00 app[worker.2]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
2012-04-01T11:44:11+00:00 app[worker.2]: 
2012-04-01T11:44:11+00:00 app[worker.2]: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
2012-04-01T11:44:12+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: Process exited with status 1
2012-04-01T11:44:12+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: State changed from up to crashed
2012-04-01T11:44:12+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-04-01T11:44:12+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: State changed from created to starting
2012-04-01T11:44:13+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake aborted!
2012-04-01T11:44:13+00:00 app[worker.1]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
2012-04-01T11:44:13+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2012-04-01T11:44:13+00:00 app[worker.1]: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
2012-04-01T11:44:14+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-04-01T11:44:14+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2012-04-01T11:44:14+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-04-01T11:44:14+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-04-01T11:44:16+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
2012-04-01T11:44:17+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: State changed from starting to up
2012-04-01T11:44:18+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
2012-04-01T11:44:19+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-04-01T11:44:20+00:00 app[worker.2]: rake aborted!
2012-04-01T11:44:20+00:00 app[worker.2]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
2012-04-01T11:44:20+00:00 app[worker.2]: 
2012-04-01T11:44:20+00:00 app[worker.2]: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
2012-04-01T11:44:22+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: Process exited with status 1
2012-04-01T11:44:22+00:00 heroku[worker.2]: State changed from up to crashed
2012-04-01T11:44:22+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake aborted!
2012-04-01T11:44:22+00:00 app[worker.1]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
2012-04-01T11:44:22+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2012-04-01T11:44:22+00:00 app[worker.1]: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
2012-04-01T11:44:23+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-04-01T11:44:23+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.2)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.2)
    activemodel (3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
    activesupport (3.1.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    addressable (2.2.7)
    arel (2.2.3)
    authlogic (3.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.7)
      activerecord (>= 3.0.7)
    builder (3.0.0)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    heroku (2.23.0)
      launchy (>= 0.3.2)
      netrc (~> 0.7.1)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      rubyzip 
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.16)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.5.1)
    launchy (2.1.0)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    mail (2.3.3)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.18)
    multi_json (1.2.0)
    netrc (0.7.1)
    pg (0.13.2)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.3.6)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activerecord (= 3.1.1)
      activeresource (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.1)
    railties (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rubyzip (0.9.4)
    sass (3.1.15)
    sass-rails (3.1.4) 
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.4)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.0)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    sequel (3.20.0)   
    sinatra (1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    sprockets (2.0.3)
       hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.4)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
      sqlite3 (>= 1.3.3)
    taps (0.3.23)
       rack (>= 1.0.1)
      rest-client (>= 1.4.0, < 1.7.0)
      sequel (~> 3.20.0)
      sinatra (~> 1.0.0)
      sqlite3-ruby (~> 1.2)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    twiliolib (2.0.7)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    tzinfo (0.3.32)
    uglifier (1.2.4)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  authlogic
  coffee-rails (~> 3.1.1)
  heroku
  jquery-rails
  json
  pg
  rails (= 3.1.1)
  sass-rails (~> 3.1.4)
  sqlite3
  taps
  twiliolib
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Heroku push with gems listed

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
-----> Configure Rails to log to stdout
       Installing rails_log_stdout... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
        Using --without development:test
        Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
       Installing rake (0.9.2.2) 
       Installing multi_json (1.2.0) 
       Installing activesupport (3.1.1)    
       Installing builder (3.0.0) 
       Installing i18n (0.6.0) 
       Installing activemodel (3.1.1) 
       Installing erubis (2.7.0) 
       Installing rack (1.3.6) 
       Installing rack-cache (1.2) 
       Installing rack-mount (0.8.3) 
       Installing rack-test (0.6.1) 
       Installing hike (1.2.1) 
       Installing tilt (1.3.3) 
       Installing sprockets (2.0.3) 
       Installing actionpack (3.1.1) 
       Installing mime-types (1.18) 
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3) 
       Installing treetop (1.4.10) 
       Installing mail (2.3.3) 
       Installing actionmailer (3.1.1) 
       Installing arel (2.2.3) 
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.32) 
       Installing activerecord (3.1.1) 
       Installing activeresource (3.1.1) 
       Installing addressable (2.2.7) 
       Installing authlogic (3.1.0) 
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.2.0) 
       Installing execjs (1.3.0) 
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0) 
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
       Installing json (1.5.1) with native extensions 
       Installing rdoc (3.12) 
       Installing thor (0.14.6) 
       Installing railties (3.1.1) 
       Installing coffee-rails (3.1.1) 
       Installing launchy (2.1.0) 
       Installing netrc (0.7.1) 
       Installing rest-client (1.6.7) 
       Installing rubyzip (0.9.4) 
       Installing heroku (2.23.0) 
       Installing jquery-rails (1.0.16) 
       Installing pg (0.13.2) with native extensions 
       Using bundler (1.0.7) 
       Installing rails (3.1.1) 
       Installing sass (3.1.15) 
       Installing sass-rails (3.1.4) 
       Installing sequel (3.20.0) 
       Installing sinatra (1.0) 
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.4) with native extensions 
       Installing sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3) 
       Installing taps (0.3.23) 
       Installing twiliolib (2.0.7) 
       Installing uglifier (1.2.4) 
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./.bundle/gems/
-----> Compiled slug size is 7.8MB
-----> Launching... done, v4
```

heroku stack yields this:

```
  aspen-mri-1.8.6
* bamboo-mri-1.9.2
  bamboo-ree-1.8.7
  cedar (beta)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worker dynos work exclusively on Delayed Job tasks.

If you don't have Delayed Job installed, then you shouldn't be scaling your worker count (which is what takes care of DJ Jobs).

If you mean to scale your web dynos, then simply scale web=2 or whatever you desire.

I'm guessing your error is because your newly scaled DJ workers can't find any jobs to do, and it errors out.

Scale worker=0 and see if that fixes it.

And if you want to scale your web dynos for better performance, web is what you're looking for.

More documentation about Heroku dyno types here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling